# Access + VBA: Correct creation of database

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, vba

how to correct create db with following fields:

```
Dim F As String
Dim S As Long
Dim T As Integer
Dim C As Double //Currency
Dim D As String //Date


F = "ABC"
S = 88869045
T = 9   
C = 30.4493 // currency, but can be double
D = "06.08.2010" // date (how to correct convert to date?) //#1

DBTable.Name = "TestTable"
DBTable.Columns.Append "First", adVarWChar, 40
DBTable.Columns.Append 1, adBigInt, 20
DBTable.Columns.Append 0, adInteger
DBTable.Columns.Append 0, adCurrency
DBTable.Columns.Append 0, adDate

DBCatalog.Tables.Append DBTable
```

also, `DBCatalog as ADOX.Catalog` and `DBTable as ADOX.Table`.

see also additional question at `#1`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Access version is 2000 or later, you can use the `Replace()` function to substitute dashes for the dots in your date string.  Then the `CDate()` function will be able to convert the string to a Date/Time value.

```
Debug.Print CDate(Replace("06.08.2010",".","-"))
6/8/2010
```

That was an example from the Immediate window on my system, which uses US as its locale setting.  So `CDate()` can accept a string containing a date in mm-dd-yyyy format.  If your locale is different, you will need to put in more work to get what you need.

Comment: thanks:) `D = CDate("20/12/2010")` works for me:) and `MsgBox D` shows `20.12.2010` :)

Answer (score 1):

all works fine with this:

```
//create database
DBTable.Name = "TestTable"
DBTable.Columns.Append "First", adVarWChar, 40
DBTable.Columns.Append "Second", adDouble, 40
DBTable.Columns.Append "Third", adInteger
DBTable.Columns.Append "Forth", adCurrency
DBTable.Columns.Append "Fifth", adDate
```

But question about convertion string to date still open:

```
Dim D as String //must be date 
D = "06.10.2010"
```

how to convert it to date and after that insert into db? (types `adDate` and Date are compatible?)

So, show a last version of code:

```
// after this: insert data into datatable (not in question, but part of creation db (usage is necessary))
Dim F As String
Dim S As Double
Dim T As Integer
Dim C As Double
Dim D As Date

Dim SS As String
Dim TS As String
Dim CS As String
Dim DS As String

F = "'" + "ABC ABD ACS" + "'" //use of single (') quote
S = 88869045
T = 9
C = 30.4493
D = CDate("20/12/2010") // for any data type! don't forget about it

SS = "'" + Str(S) + "'"
TS = "'" + Str(T) + "'"
CS = "'" + Str(C) + "'"
DS = "'" + Str(D) + "'"

DBConnection.Execute "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES  (" + F + "," + SS + "," + TS + "," + CS + "," + DS + " ) "
```

P.S. it works fine, thanks for comments and answers.

Comment: thanks! change it to full answer for my question with your help, @HasnUP. maybe not optimal, but work